# DryIoc with MediatR: IAsyncRequestHandler Resolve exception

Tags: dryioc

DryIoc can't seem to Resolve a IAsyncRequestHandler.
It throws
"*An exception of type 'DryIoc.ContainerException' occurred in DryIoc.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Unable to resolve MediatR.IRequestHandler.
Where no service registrations found
  and number of Rules.FallbackContainers: 0
  and number of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers: 0*"
which is weird because it should be resolving a IAsyncRequestHandler.
Another weird thing is that the code runs well on Net.Fiddle (check [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fQ9bmC))

I'm using VS 2015 Update 3 in Windows 10 Home, MediatR 3.0.0, DryIoc.dll 2.10.0, .Net framework 4.5 (also tried with 4.6.1).
Am I registering it in a wrong way? This should be straightforward.
Related: What is the best way to register all handlers?

Comment: Did you try to use this example from MediatR repo https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.DryIoc/Program.cs

Comment: Yes, along with some other articles. I Just can't figure out the reason for the exception. Did you find anything wrong in the Net.Fiddle code that could explain the exception? What about the best way to register all IAsyncRequestHandler<> and IAsyncRequestHandler<,> automatically?

Comment: Did you try RegisterMany with your handlers assemblies as in example?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem in my code. Thanks. Regarding the RegisterMany question: Isn't it registering all Interfaces found in both assemblies? Suppose I just want to register automatically IAsyncRequestHandler interfaces?

Comment: You can filter interfaces you need in condition.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to register only the IAsyncRequestHandler using `container.RegisterMany(new[] { GetType().GetAssembly()}, type => type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IAsyncRequestHandler<,>));`. But I'm stuck with MediatR 2.1.0. MediatR 3.0.0 keeps throwing the mentioned exception.

Comment: I don't know, they did some breaking changes in MediatR 3. And did not yet have a chance to play with it. Given that dotnetfiddle works, it may be something in your setup, e.g. two dlls where you would expect one, or some type being internal instead of public, etc.